# THIS referent to the Object

Tags: this, javascript-objects

Why THIS, in my code change the default color not what i set.

```
<div>
<p id="demo" name="demo" onmouseover="this.style='green'">Seine Name ist;</p>
</div>
<hr>
<button id="buty" name="buty" onclick="colory();">Click</button>


<script>
function colory(){`enter code here`
document.getElementById('demo').style.color='red';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `this.style` to `this.style.color`.
You can also change the color back to 'black' or 'red' using `onmouseout`

```js
function colory() {
  `enter code here`
  document.getElementById('demo').style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="demo" name="demo" onmouseover="this.style.color='green'">Seine Name ist;</p>
</div>
<hr>
<button id="buty" name="buty" onclick="colory();">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but now when I move the mouse just near the Text

Comment: Please accept my answer if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer, but now there is another problem, which is; when I move the mouse just near or around the Text, it change the color to green, my question is, why not just over the text which is the function of onmouseover?